# How do I report a typo (by sending a diff file)?

Tags: r

I would like to make correcting typos as easy as possible for the R developers. How can I send a diff file making such a "patch"?

Also, where should I send the typo? Through email? Post a bug? Send it to r-devel?

I am mostly concerned with small typos, such as misspellings or grammatical corrections.

I can't recall where the last typo I saw was, but only as an example, let's just suppose I would like to change "back" to "backward" in "back compatibility in the help file for ls. How can I make a diff patch?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@David Alber's advice about diff formats is good (although I often use `diff -c` instead), but I beg to differ about the best target (he suggests `bug.report` and the R bug tracking system).

- For simple typographical errors, a quick e-mail with sufficient, informal context to the `r-devel@r-project.org` mailing list is usually best (make sure you are using the latest version! -- see next point).  This is how I do it, and it seems to be preferred by the R developers because it means they don't have to deal with the full bug-reporting machinery. (The only documentation of that protocol I can easily find is this [note from Brian Ripley in 2007](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.devel/13167/).)
- If you're going to report errors more systematically, the best thing if you can stand to make the investment would be to get the latest Subversion release from https://svn.R-project.org/R/trunk (there is a brief although slightly outdated description [here](http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/)), make the changes to the Rd file, and then run an `svn diff` to get diffs against the latest version. As above, send it to `r-devel` (I believe text-file attachments are preserved in e-mail to `r-devel`).
- Don't forget the usual cautions about sending bug reports: (1) make sure you are reporting against the most recent version (as above, SVN is best if you can stand it); (2) make sure whatever you report is *definitely* a bug/typo; (3) make sure to report to the appropriate authorities, i.e. report bugs/typos in contributed packages to the maintainer (the relevant package should be listed at the head of the help file, and `maintainer("pkg")` finds the e-mail address of the maintainer).

Comment: I can give a more recent (from March 2011) citation for the protocol: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14540#c1

Comment: @Ben Thank you, Ben! All of this sounds like good advice! Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 4):

Patches are often made using the unified context diff. You can create such a diff using `diff -u`.

For example, let's say you start with file `foo` with the following contents.

```
Blah
Blah
Blah
```

Then you modify it, saving the modifications in a new file called `foo.modified`. Here are the contents of `foo.modified`:

```
Blah
Blah
New information!
Blah -- changing this line
```

Now doing `diff -u foo foo.modified` produces the following.

```
--- foo 2011-11-05 20:59:13.000000000 -0700
+++ foo.modified    2011-11-05 20:59:44.000000000 -0700
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 Blah
 Blah
-Blah
+New information!
+Blah -- changing this line
```

Note that many revision control systems' diffs display the unified context diff.

As for where to send bugs in R: it looks like there is a built-in function for that: [`bug.report`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/bug.report.html). Alternatively, there is the web interface to the [R bug tracking system](http://bugs.r-project.org/).